# Unrecognized VM option

Tags: java, jvm

I have seen an issue with ReduceInitialCardMarks, where sometimes on the same JVM on one machine it does not recognize this VM option were as on another machine it works perfectly fine.
The VM does not start.
What is making it fail sometimes ?
When does an unrecognized VM option occur ?

Comment: Check if there are spaces in the path of the VM. Are you on Windows or Mac or Linux? What option was not recognized?

Comment: How do you start it? How you specify the option? What is the error log?

Comment: java version "1.6.0_18" is the java version. It's Linux machines.
The option is specified as -XX:-ReduceInitialCardMarks and it is started by a script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is with the VM.
Java Server VM recognizes this option while Java Client VM does not.

Answer (score 0):

Type `java` without parameters to see that the particular virtual machine supports. Type `java -X` to see help on extended options. Especially extended options may not work on other virtual machines, only very few of them (like `-Xmx`) are somewhat more standard.

Your question does not contain enough information to advice anything more.

Comment: java -X provides a list of very few options. while there are many more options that can be used.
The question here is on one machine the same JVM throws an unrecognized option for ReduceInitialCardMarks while on another machine the same JVM accepts it and works perfectly fine. Why this odd behavior by the JVM ?